# HTML Issues with images

Tags: html, image, xenforo

I have set up a page and I have a html code for team logos to have text in once you hover over them. What I cant get is why both images are the same when they have two different links on the page for 2 different images. Why are the images not on the same line. One on the left and one in the middle. And finally how to I add a link into this. Below is the webpage and the code.

Click on the team you wish to manage and proceed to your sponsorship deal!

.pic{ width:350px; height:220px; background: url(http://oi67.tinypic.com/8xj85v.jpg) no-repeat; } .text{ width:290px; height:160px; background:#303030; opacity:0; } .pic:hover .text { opacity:0.8; text-align:justify; color:#fff; font-size:10.5px; font-weight:500; font-family:"Arial", Times, serif; padding:30px; }      Scuderia Ferrari are the most successful and oldest currently competing team in Formula One. They are based in Maranello, Italy.

Founded in 1929, the team started making their own cars in 1947 after running Alfa Romeos until then. They were part of the inaugural World Championship in 1950.

Ferrari have won the drivers' title fifteen times, in 1952, 1953, 1956, 1958, 1961, 1964, 1975, 1977, 1979, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004 and 2007. They won the Constructors' Championship (which was formed in 1958) sixteen times, in 1961, 1964, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1979, 1982, 1983, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2007 and 2008.

.pic{ width:350px; height:220px; background: url(http://oi67.tinypic.com/2vjtz5u.jpg) no-repeat; } .text{ width:290px; height:160px; background:#303030; opacity:0; } .pic:hover .text { opacity:0.8; text-align:justify; color:#fff; font-size:10.5px; font-weight:500; font-family:"Arial", Times, serif; padding:30px; }      Mercedes AMG Petronas Formula One Team, previously Mercedes GP Petronas F1 Team, is a Formula One racing team, based in Brackley, United Kingdom, using a German licence. Mercedes had been involved in the pre-war European Championship and breifly in Formula One during 1954 and 1955.
 Mercedes-Benz returned to Formula One for the 2010 season after buying a minority stake (45.1%) in the Brawn GP team and have since become multiple contractors winners with a superior package in the turbo era.

Comment: http://www.xciteracingleague.com/pages/Teammanagement/

Answer (score 0):

#### 1) Same image:

The main problem is lack of specificity in your CSS.
`.pic` is defined twice - first in the inline `<style>` tag within the outermost `<left>` tag which is followed by the `.pic` DIV; the second in the child `<center>` tag which is also followed by an inline `<style>` tag. If you inspect the `.pic` DIV(s), you'll notice that the second CSS `.pic` declaration stomps on the previous declaration.
[image]

To fix this:

1. Move all your CSS into one file loaded in the HTML `<head>` tag.
2. Add specificity; a few options for you:

**A) Add specificity in with tag-name**

```
left > .pic {
    background-image: url(A);
}

center > .pic {
    background-image: url(B);
}
```

**B) Add specificity with additional class-name**
    .pic.first {
        background-image: url(A);
    }

```
.pic.second {
    background-image: url(A);
}
```

---

#### 2) Not on same line:

To fix this:

1. The `<left>` and `<center>` tags are block-level elements - so you can define those in CSS as `left, center { display: inline-block; }`
2. Remove the `<br>` between them

---

#### 3) Add a link:

To fix this:

Simply wrap each set of `.img` and `.text` DIVs in an `<a href= ...> ... </a>` anchor-tag